# Taxonomic clasification of BLAST output

Tags: bioinformatics

I am working with Next Generation Sequencing. I BLASTed the bovine de novo assembled contigs to the NCBI nucleotide database. I got a matching with a lot of species i.e. different kind of bacteria, viruses and mammals. I want them to group in a logical way i.e. all the bacteria in one group (bacteria group) similarly viruses and mammals. This is hard to arrange manually, can anybody help how I can arrange my vast number of species into some logical grouping. Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: I think this question is missing a few key details for it to be answerable. Do you have the NCBI IDs? A "logical way" will depend on protein context (membrane or globular, what is the enzymatic function, etc). Would the super-kingdoms be enough resolution?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically metagenomics.
Congratulations, you already did the most time consuming step. 
There are several ways to go from there, but I will talk about the one I know best.
There is the metagenomic analysis tool [MEGAN](http://ab.inf.uni-tuebingen.de/data/software/megan6/download/welcome.html). It can read your Blast Output, if it is in the correct format (normal XML or tabular) and will automatically do what you want. 
For a start, just use the default values, for more help you an then go to the [Community Website](http://megan.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de) of MEGAN for help.

Analysing your data may take a little, depending on how many contigs you have. But if you were able to blast them in reasonable time it should be no problem. As I said, you are through the most time consuming step already.